# How to update web page by sending POST request with parameter to it AND get the last retrieved paramter value by sending GET request to it

Tags: html, asp-classic

I need to write a simple web page that can be update by POST of a parameter:

1. Sending POST request to the page with a parameter - will update the web page constantly.
2. Sending GET request to the page will return the last retrieved value of the parameter

For example (Probably each request is a different session):

```
POST /mypage.asp?param1=Hello

GET /mypage.asp  >>  Response: Hello

POST /mypage.asp?param1=Changed

GET /mypage.asp  >>  Response: Changed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%
dim fileSystemObject,Text_File,Text_File_Content,NewValue

NewValue=Request.QueryString("MyParam")
set fileSystemObject=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If NewValue <> "" Then
    set Text_File=fileSystemObject.CreateTextFile("C:\MyPath\myTextFile.txt")
    Text_File.write(NewValue)
    Text_File.close
End If

if fileSystemObject.FileExists("C:\MyPath\myTextFile.txt")=true then
    set Text_File=fileSystemObject.OpenTextFile("C:\MyPath\myTextFile.txt",1,false)
    Text_File_Content=Text_File.ReadAll
    Text_File.close
else
    set Text_File=fileSystemObject.CreateTextFile("C:\MyPath\myTextFile.txt")
    Text_File.write("Please send GET request to this page with paramter MyParam!")
    Text_File.close
    set Text_File=fileSystemObject.OpenTextFile("C:\MyPath\myTextFile.txt",1,false)
    Text_File_Content=Text_File.ReadAll
    Text_File.close
end if

Response.Write(Text_File_Content)
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SESSION

```
session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    $_SESSION['last_val'] = $_POST['some_val'];
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET")
    echo $_SESSION['last_val'];
}
```

[Learn more about SESSION](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php)

Comment: I need to web page to return the value of the post parameter when I'll send GET request to it

Comment: You said `post` in your OP

Comment: POST to the page - updates it. GET - retrieve the last POSTed parameter

Comment: Okay you need to update your question in a major way then, I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: @SharonBL See my answer, use SESSION

Comment: Does the SESSION option keeps the value constant on the page for other users sessions?

Comment: @SharonBL Yes, just include `session_start()` to the top of any page that you want to use sessions

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27783/discussion-between-evan-and-sharonbl)

Answer (score 0):

Evan's answer is correct conceptually, but I think he doesn't address the different sessions and didn't use "classic ASP" (vbscript or jscript).

To persist a value between sessions and requests, you need some form of storage. Probably the simplest option is an Application variable (which I show below). Other options are "thread-safe" storage, like the widely available CAPROCK DICTIONARY, or a database.

The code:

```
<%@ Language="VBScript" %> 
<% 
If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD")= "POST" Then
 Application.Lock  
 Application("StoredValue") = Request.Form("param1") 
 Application.Unlock  
Else
 Application.Lock  
 Response.Write Application("StoredValue") 
 Application.Unlock
End If
%>
```